# Docker: coudn't expose a service

Tags: docker, gunicorn

Couldn't manage simple task I did before many times *(I've updated Docker few days ago if it matters and had a lot of errors with docker-compose which couldn't even give a version)*: run a container locally and access an exposed path. Simple, but I have an `Error 61. Connection refused`

What I do:

1. `docker build container_name .` -- in a Dockerfile I exposed both 80 and 5000
2. `docker run -d -p 80:5000 container_name`
3. Chech my `docker-machine dev ip` address on port `80` -- connection refused.

Inside the container I have a running gunicorn on port 5000. It works fine. 
When I login to the container I could easily `curl localhost:5000`. And have a fine response from working server on `localhost:5000`.

So I need only map port 80 on my host to port 5000 inside the container, that's what the cmd `-p 80:5000` should do, right? But it doesn't work. What do I do wrong?

---

`docker version`:

```
Client:
  Version:      1.9.1
  API version:  1.21
  Go version:   go1.4.3
  Git commit:   a34a1d5
  Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
  OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
  Version:      1.9.1
  API version:  1.21
  Go version:   go1.4.3
  Git commit:   a34a1d5
  Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't listen to `localhost` listen to `0.0.0.0` (or `*` depending on how the config does it)

`localhost` is specifically loop back *within your container*. To port map to host, you'll need to listen to a non-loopback address.

You don't need to `EXPOSE` if you're specifying `-p` though - that does it implicitly.